# Install Kubernetes on Alpine Linux armhf

Tags: kubernetes, raspberry-pi, alpine-linux

I would like to install Kubernetes on Alpine Linux which runs on a Raspberry Pi (ARM architecture). So far I've only found K8s packages for x86_64 but nothing for armhf...
Any ideas/workarounds would be very much appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since [April/2016](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/17981) Kubernetes on ARM archtectures is native.

And there is an [official package](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/testing/x86_64/kubernetes) in Alpine repositories.

So run `apk add kubernetes` should works.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Mauro. Unfortunately, I don't think that K8s can be installed on Linux Alpine running on ARM yet. Do you know if there's been any significant updates on this?